# YUP validation - how to get the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I got the following piece of code :

```
    name: yup
      .string()
      .trim()
      .required(message("nameMissing"))
      .max(40, message("nameTooLongWithStatus", {
        length: (HERE I NEED HELP),
      })),
```

Refer to the line where I wrote "HERE I NEED HELP".
I want it to be something like:  `name.toString().length`

But this obviously doesnt work, actually nothing that I tried worked.
I simply want to get the value of  'name' and get it's length, that is all.

So the idea is that, "name" should be a string with at most 40 characters. If it is more than 40, a message will be displyed saying "The maximum character count is 40 (current length)" where current length is the name you provided as input.

`message("nameTooLongWithStatus"` will accept a parameter "length" and will construct the said message.

Comment: You say "nothing that I tried worked" but what are you trying to do? Please be more clear because saying "I want it to be something like: name.toString().length" does'nt explain what that should be doing. How exactly you want to validate `name`?

Comment: So 'name' should be a string of maximum 40 chars. Whatever goes beyond 40, a message should say that it's over 40 and provide the current length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get these fields if you provide a function as a second argument to `max()`.

`path,value,originalValue,label,max`

```
name: Yup.string()
.trim()
.max(5, (obj) => {
  const valueLength = obj.value.length;
  return `Name (length: ${valueLength}) cannot be more than ${obj.max}`;
})
.required('Required')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy, but you will need to use the [`.test`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema) method, do your own validation and call `this.createError` passing the `message` with the value you will receive from `.test`.

```
name: yup
  .string()
  .trim()
  .required(message("nameMissing"))
  .test('test_length_greater_than_40', '', function(value){
      // your condition
      if(value && value.toString().length > 40){
          // setting the error message using the value's length
          return this.createError({ message: `someErrorMessage ${value.toString().length}` })
      }
      return true
  }),
```

There is other ways of doing this too, like setting the `params` and getting it in the `message` (which is the second argument of `test`). If you want to do that way, you can take a look at the docs, but it's pretty much the same.

*Also notice this from the docs*

> Please note that to use the this context the test function must be a function expression (function test(value) {}), not an arrow function, since arrow functions have lexical context.

Comment: Tried and it works, but there is another solution @ this question using .max, so I preffered to use that one

Answer (score 0):

You can make profit of the length's message second argument:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .length(10, (elt)=> `${elt.originalValue ? elt.originalValue.length : "0" }`)
})
```

Then, if you validate:

```
await schema.validate(
  { name: "AAA" },
  {
    strict: false,
    abortEarly: false,
  }
);
```

You will get a ValidationError with the length of the input :

```
  Array [
    [ValidationError: 3],
  ]
```