# Is it possible to show a string length inside of a yup error message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Currently, our validation schema looks something like this:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  statuses: Yup.array().of(
      value: Yup.string().when('deleted', {
        is: false,
        then: Yup.string()
          .nullable()
          .max(64, 'Must be less than 64 characters'),
      }),
      available_on_label: Yup.string().when('deleted', {
        is: false,
        then: Yup.string()
          .nullable()
          .max(15, 'Must be less than 15 characters'),
      }),
    })
  ),
})
```

I would like to make the error message on `available_on_label` show the current character count of that field. Something like:

.max(15, `Must be less than 15 characters. (${Yup.String().length()} / 15)`),

I have tried to access the string inside of the validation, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Look like the same as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891269/yup-validation-how-to-get-the-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YUP validation - how to get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891269/yup-validation-how-to-get-the-value)

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: [YUP validation - how to get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891269/yup-validation-how-to-get-the-value)

Leaving this post in case it helps someone else source the answer

```
.max(15, (obj) => {
            const length = obj.value.length;
            return `Must be less than 15 characters (${length} / 15)`;
          })
```